# Add two array list in same spinner with seperation in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner, dropdown

I want to add two array list in the same spinner and when i click on `spinner` it should show two list separated with label, so that i can select item from any of the list in same `spinner`. how can i achieve this in `android`.

Currently i am doing like this, is it correct way to do this?

```
private void myFunction(){

    ArrayList<String> arrayListOne = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListOne.add("LABEL NAME");

    for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){

        arrayListOne.add("name"+i);

    }

    ArrayList<String> arrayListTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListTwo.add("LABEL DESIGNATION");

    for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){

        arrayListOne.add("designation"+i);

    }

    arrayListOne.addAll(arrayListTwo);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayListOne);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    
}
```

Solution: So to achieve this I have created my own library [Check this](https://github.com/yatindeokar/DualMultiSelectionSpinner)

Comment: where is your code and concept ui? if you would not show us what you have done till now, no one gonna write code for you, downvotes are coming soon .

Comment: Welcome to SO . The only you can get here with this question is negative votes. Cause it does not show any research effort( No code ) . Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For this question you need to create three arraylist which you can use according it:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayOne=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
arrayOne.add(" "+i);
}

ArrayList<String> arrayTwo=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)
{
arrayTwo.add(" "+j);
}

after that you should merge both arraylist into one  using this:


ArrayList<String> arrayFinal=new ArrayList<String>();
 for(k=0;k<arrayOne.size();k++)
{
arrayFinal.add(arrayOne.get(k));
}

for(u=0;u<arrayTwo.size();u++)
{
arrayFinal.add(arrayTwo.get(u));
}
```

Now you can find a singal arraylist with merge two arraylist data, now you can initialize your spinner by final arraylist data.

make a custom adapter for where send the position of that place where you want to disable the label
using this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<String> ayylist;
    Context context;
int postionDisable;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> ayylist,int postionDisable) {
        this.ayylist = ayylist;
        this.context = context;
        this.postionDisable=postionDisable;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ayylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ayylist.get(position);
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (position == postionDisable) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simpletext1, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView);
        textView.setText(ayylist.get(position).toString());
        textView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor));
        if (position == postionDisable) {
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            textView.setTextSize(15);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i add label for lists and disable label only

Comment: here u can add a key before the add second arraylist in final arraylist using
arrayFinal.add("tag for second");

Comment: check my edited code and custom adapter: in custom adapter pass three arg 1.context 2. araylist 3. position.
in third position pass "arrayOne.size()+1" value;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790242/spinner-data-from-server can any one help me out